# Confluence API and fetching page content without logging in

Tags: rest, confluence

Does the confluence REST API allow for getting the pages without logging in, ie, without using username and password? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are protected by space permissions or page restrictions, you still need to authenticate.  Obtain session cookies and send them along with your REST requests.